# Single line command to open a list of files from another program such as Git, PowerShell, or Command Line

Tags: git, powershell, command-line, visual-studio-code

I would like to open all the changed files from a branch in VS Code.

Right now I am doing that in two steps.

```
// copy the file list
PS> git diff master... --name-only | clip

// paste the file list
PS> code file1 file2 file3 ... fileN
```

How, if at all, can we do that in one line? What I have tried are these two approaches:

```
PS> git diff master... --name-only | code 
PS> git diff master... --name-only | code -
```

Reference to [VS Code CLI docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_opening-files-and-folders).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`,(git diff master... --name-only) |  % { code $_ }`

The comma at the beginning [creates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#comma-operator-) an array with a single element that is passed down the pipeline. So in the foreach, there is only one iteration which passes the array of filenames to code.

I haven't tested this with whitespace in the file paths.

Alternatively, without pushing things down the pipeline you can just do

`code (git diff signage-theme... --name-only)`

Comment: This is useful and might be the answer. I will play around with it. The only downside is having to wrap the git command in parentheses. It would be great just to pipe the original git output into a single array instead of having to use the `,(<some-command>)` approach. Something along the lines of `the git command | reduce to single array | % { code $_ }` would be better though perhaps quixotic to expect.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin External commands already send their output as an array of strings which is why the unary array operator is needed so it doesn't get unrolled.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the other answer in case of filenames containing spaces:

```
#requires -Version 4
$files = @(& git.exe diff master... --name-only).
    ForEach{"""$PSItem"""} -join ' '
& code.cmd $files
```

This solution makes use of embedded quotes which the `cmd` parser will strip away if they're not needed.

Comment: This is useful info albeit impractical for my use case, which requires that the code be a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

You can **pass the output of the `git` command to `code` as an *argument***:

```
code (git diff master... --name-only)
```

**PowerShell collects the stdout output lines from an external program in an *array*.**

Assuming that the `git` command outputs file paths only, each on its own line, **passing that array to another external program** such as `code` automatically **passes the array's elements as *individual*, *appropriately quoted* arguments.**

For instance, on Windows, if you ran the following:

```
code (cmd /c echo file1`& echo "file 2")
```

`code` would see a command line such as the following:

```
...\code.cmd "file1" "file 2"
```

---

Note that **(direct) *piping* to `code` is not an option**, because `code` doesn't accept *file paths* from stdin; you can use stdin to pass a (new) file's *content*, however (`'Text for new doc' | code -`).

**There is *no* benefit to using the pipeline via PowerShell's `ForEach-Object` cmdlet here**.